# GitLab Omniauth restricted for select GitHub organization members

Tags: github, omniauth, gitlab

I have a GitLab running for my Github Organization members to log in. I have configured GitLab to use GitHub to login. I know that I can set GitLab to block every new user, so that I can manually unblock them as I want.

GitHub announced last year that you can now select new [scopes](https://developer.github.com/changes/2014-02-25-organization-oauth-scopes/) such as

```
read:org
```

which allows my GitLab to get the user's organizations. Is it possible to configure GitLab to create new users only for members of my organization? If not, I don't want to fork the code and implement it myself, but a plug-in solution would also do the trick. Any advice?